# "can't use starred expression here"

Tags: python

I would like to return two things instead of a list of two elements. I could use `return sorted_list[0], sorted_list[1]` but I guess it would be less time-efficient. So I wanted to unpack the list directly in the return statement to time the two solutions and pick the quickest one but it doesn't work. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
def sort_two_str(str1: str, str2: str):
    return *sorted((str1, str2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sort_two_str("A2", "A1"))
```

Output:

```
  File "path/to/file.py", line 2
    return *sorted((str1, str2))
           ^
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Comment: You can't return two things. You can only return one value, but it can be a container like a list (as sorted returns) or tuple (which is what `return sorted_list[0], sorted_list[1]` returns).

Comment: I can do `return a, b` in python right?

Comment: Yes. That's returning _one value_, which is a tuple.

Comment: how come `str1, str2 = *sorted((str1, str2))` doesn't work then instead of the return statement?

Comment: `a = 1, 2` `print(type(a))  # <class 'tuple'>`

Comment: Because you can't use a starred expression there. What are you unpacking _into_?

Comment: You can do `str1, str = sorted((str1, str2))`

Comment: I want to unpack it into the two variables str1 and str2. I might be misunderstanding something about how unpacking work

Comment: _Into_ those two variables? They're the _inputs_. What you're asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think I just got it sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return two things... Also I suggest avoid thinking about these micro-optimizations.

If you return an iterable which has two items, you can then unpack it like:

```py
a, b = func()
```

Interestingly if you add a single `,` after your expression, it becomes valid. In fact it gets turned into tuple.

```py
def sort_two_str(str1: str, str2: str):
    return *sorted((str1, str2)),
```

Comment: Just to expand, that tuple will have len() of 1, with the first element being what would be the return without a comma.

Comment: "If you return an iterable which has two items, you can then unpack it like: `a, b = func()`" so basically the star expression is only ever used in functions to know if you want two arguments or one argument which is an iterable?

Comment: @IuriGuilherme Tuple will have the length of 2. It's like just returning `sorted((str1, str2))` but it is not a list anymore. It's a tuple.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Another useful case that came into my mind is unpacking like : `first, *rest = function()`. Here everything except the first item will be stored in the `rest`. But mostly we use it in the callable's when we are defining or passing arguments to.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary yep, I just tested here and this seems to be an edge case. Interesting, I will research more before using this on production

Comment: I'm struggling to understand whatever is the rationale between `*sorted((str1, str2)),` working but I guess it isn't that important

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows When you say `var = 1, 2`, you defined a tuple although it doesn't have parentheses. *Comma* is what turns it to tuple. Now imagine instead of first item which is `1`, you have a list `[3, 4]` and you unpack it. `3` and `4` become the first and second elements of the tuple. `var = *[3, 4], 2`. Another example is `var = (1, 2,  *[3, 4])`.

Comment: Ohh insightful thanks!